# Why does my scanner iterate twice once and then once all other times that I input something that is not an integer?

Tags: java

What I really want my program to do is iterate once every time, but when I run code, the first time I try to follow the constraints, it asks me to enter a number between 1 and 7 twice, and after I I go through one trial, the code flows as desired.

```
//import libraries
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Milestone1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //define variables
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int patternDes = 0;
    boolean world[][] = new boolean[Config.WORLD_ROWS][Config.WORLD_COLUMNS];


    //print statements 
    System.out.println("Welcome to Conway's Game Of Life");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    System.out.println("1)Glider 2)Beacon 3)Beehive 4)R-pentomino");
    System.out.println("5)Random 6)Custom or 7)Exit");
    System.out.print("Choose a pattern:");

    //Have the scanner choose a pattern
    patternDes = scnr.nextInt();

    //check constraints
    while(!(patternDes <= 7 &&  patternDes >= 1))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 7: ");
        if(!scnr.hasNextInt()){
            scnr.nextLine();
            continue;
        }
        else{
            patternDes = scnr.nextInt();
            if((patternDes <= 7 && patternDes >= 1)){
                break;
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    //write another while loop now

}

}
```

This has also happened in many other codes, and it takes me forever to fix the particular method.

Comment: Can you provide some more information or paste your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
int patternDes;
do {
   System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 7: ");
   patternDes = scnr.nextInt();
}while (patternDes <= 7 && patternDes >= 1);
```